# Stock Mail App - Outlook Sync, File As Problem

Tags: htc-desire, email, outlook

My MD now has a Desire and I notice something strange happening when he syncs his outlook contacts.

Now I know from both sides (outlook, Android) , it doesn't really matter what you file someone's name as because when you search, it still appears either way. However, he is very particular so here is my problem.

When he syncs his outlook contacts to the device, on outlook they now appear as first name, last name. Even though they are set to File As Lastname, Firstname. Now if I open a contact in Outlook, flip the File As back from and to what it was, it then appears in outlook correctly (well how he wants it to).

However, next sync it will re appear as first, last... although file as is still last, first (Outlook)

Anyone have any ideas or noticed something similar?

I appreciate this is a minor issue but I would like to resolve it for him if possible.

Thanks for reading and any help appreciated.

Comment: Are you doing manual sync's or is the phone connected to Exchange?

Comment: we have exchange ota services. sorry I should have added that.

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no way to do this on an HTC phone. The People app from HTC will automatically display names as First and Last.

However if you connect the phone to exchange, as I have mine, then all Exchange contacts show up as Last and First, including in Mail and in People. So as of right now I would say if you can get his phone on Exchange, only display contacts from Exchange, and tell him to put them all in Exchange, then it should be a workaround to the issue.

Comment: Yeah I apologise, I should have added this is using exchange 2007 ota services. Its as if it was correct in exchange, sync'd to his phone and then I assume he added someone new to the phone and when it sync'd back it was first Last. No worries, I will sync again with those tests I did and add a new one and sync again to find out. Thanks for the pointer on the HTC app though.

Comment: @Pace, keep in mind you might have to have Exchange setup so that is lists contacts as Last, First. Not sure but that might make a difference.